# Reading Zend Engine API code: What does ## (double hash) mean?

Tags: c, php-internals

Out of curiousity, I'm reading the Zend Engine API code and encountered quite a number of ## in their #define's. For example, at /usr/lib/php5/Zend/zend_API.h:

```
#define ZEND_FN(name) zif_##name
#define ZEND_MN(name) zim_##name
```

What does the ## (double hash) symbols mean in these two lines?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The ## concatenates what's before the ## with what's after it. So in your example doing `ZEND_FN(foo)` would result in `zif_foo`

Answer (score 6):

Echo RvV's answer.

Be aware that when concatenating literal strings you may find some inconsistencies between pre-processors/compilers. Some will require the ##

```
#define STR_CAT(s1, s2)   s1 ## s2
```

as in

```
const char s[] = STR_CAT("concat", "enation")
```

whereas other will baulk at it, and instead just require that the two literals will be joined by the compiler (as opposed to the pre-processor), so will require

```
#define STR_CAT(s1, s2)   s1 s2
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/preprocessor/sharp