# What does the symbol `mm##` in a #define mean in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

What is the `mm##` meant in C code? For example:

```c
#define REGISTER(addr) *((volatile unsigned int *)(addr))

#define abc(reg)  REGISTER(mm##reg)
```

Comment: Look up "c preprocessor concatenate"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of double hash (##) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885213/use-of-double-hash-in-c)

Comment: In short: it replaces `abc(123)` by `REGISTER(mm123)`, which in turn is being replaced by `*((volatile unsigned int *)(mm123))`.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html):

> The ‘##’ preprocessing operator performs token pasting. When a macro is expanded, the two tokens on either side of each ‘##’ operator are combined into a single token, which then replaces the ‘##’ and the two original tokens in the macro expansion. Usually both will be identifiers, or one will be an identifier and the other a preprocessing number. When pasted, they make a longer identifier. This isn’t the only valid case. It is also possible to concatenate two numbers (or a number and a name, such as 1.5 and e3) into a number. Also, multi-character operators such as += can be formed by token pasting.

In your case, it's creating a new identifier prefixed with the characters `mm`.