# What does ## mean in the #define directive in the code here

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation

Please tell  me the answer with explanation:

```
#define f(g,h) g##h

main(){
  printf("%d",f(100,10));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Zend Engine API code: What does ## (double hash) means?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653466/reading-zend-engine-api-code-what-does-double-hash-means). Other dups [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880058/double-hash-before-parameter-in-function-call),[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885213/use-of-double-hash-in-c) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059772/what-do-two-adjacent-pound-signs-mean-in-a-c-macro)

Comment: this is the macro concatenation operator, it just appends the string values of g and h

Comment: Just execte your code and you will see

Answer (score 13):

`##` is used to concatenate whatever is  before the `##` with whatever is after it. It is used for concatenation.

You can check the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) for details

> A ## operator between any two successive identifiers in the
>   replacement-list runs parameter replacement on the two identifiers
>   (which are not macro-expanded first) and then concatenates the result.
>   This operation is called "concatenation" or "token pasting".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful duplicate - [What does ## in a #define mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503586/what-does-in-a-define-mean)

**Example**

For

```
  //Definition
  #define ArgArg(x, y)     x##y

  //Example
  ArgArg(lady, bug) -> "ladybug"
```